# Firebase Auth: Is it possible to be logged in on two devices at the same time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Does Firebase Auth allow two devices to be logged in with the same account at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, It does. Firebase Auth allows user to login using different devices using same credentials.

Comment: Ok, so I could use one Account for multiple users that share this account and they can be logged in synchronyously?

Comment: i won't recommend you using a system where multiple user are using same account to login as you might have to compromise with security rules. But if it's your project requirement you can totally go it. Firebase Auth allows you to do it.

Comment: Ok thanks, in my case that's no problem I think, as all of the users with the same account should have the same rights